# Why my content is outside of the div when scroll show up?

Tags: html, css

This is my general wrap:

```
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Inside from this wrap, I have two  wrappers more, navigation and entries.

```
.wrapped-nav{
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#333;
    float:left;
    padding-top:80px;
    text-align:center;
}

.wrapped-ent{
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#666;
    float:left;
}
```

But when my content in the `nav` section it's outside and the scroll show up in the navigator, my wrap not wraps up my content.

I add this picture from the problem:

[image: problem]

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/qjLthkg2/

Comment: To assume, I can say you need to clear the applied float.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `position:absolute;` for the container.

absolute items are taken out of the normal page flow. They are like a ghost and won't expand based on the contents of it, so the inner content just flows down.

You need to rethink your styling.

Comment: Any help for making my wrap?